# C# string with particular character at end to integer

Tags: c#, string, biginteger

I could probably do this in a series of steps by looking at the last character of the string and based on what it is send it to a particular function to have the conversion made.  But I am just wondering if there is any easier way to do the following.

For example I have a string that might say something like 23.44M or 5.23B, the M and B obviously stand for "Million" or "Billion", I want to convert that string into the number it is representing but just not sure of the most efficient way to do this.  Looking for some ideas.  Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in function in .NET that implements this. The approach you describe sounds sensible.

Comment: Read the last character in the string, remove the character, then cat what you actualy want

Comment: you can write your own Switch/ Case statement and custom methods to easily handle this

Comment: Are million and billion the only suffixes you have? Can there be other characters in the string (e.g. spaces)? In the end, the method you'll write will depend mostly on what the constraints on the input string are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">The number.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static decimal GetValue(string number)
{
    char unit = number.Last();
    string num = number.Remove(number.Length - 1, 1);

    decimal multiplier;
    switch (unit)
    {
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            multiplier = 1000000; break;

        default:
            multiplier = 1; break;
    }

    return decimal.Parse(num) * multiplier;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great responses.  This method right here works great!

Comment: @Ron Would be nice if you accepted one of the solutions then.

Answer (score 6):

I would build a Dictionary, and populate it with key value pairs such as (B, 1,000,000,000) and (M, 1,000,000). Take the character off the end, look up the value for that character, and multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines work for you?

```
double num = Double.parse(inputStr.Remove(inputStr.Count-1));
char lastChar = inputStr.Last();
switch(lastChar)
{
   case 'M':
      num *= 1000000;
      break;
   case 'B':
      num *= 1000000000;
      break;
}
```

If the format of your input can vary, you would have to add additional logic, including protecting against an illegal Parse().

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is probably to use a regex ([MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx))  you could group on (this is NOT regex syntax) [numbers][char]
then you have 2 groups, the first would be your number, the second would be your "factor" character

then, convert the first with `double.TryParse()`, and run your second through a switch or a set of `if` statements to multiply as needed to get your end result.

Answer (score 0):

As a nerdy alternative to the answer by @Smelch you could populate a String constant POSTFIXES, such as "xHKxxMxxBxxTxxQ" and multiply your base by Math.Pow(10,POSTFIXES.LastIndexOf(...)+1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map chars to multipliers instead of a switch statement and use upper case only:

```
public static decimal GetValue(string number)
{
    return decimal.Parse(number.Remove(number.Length - 1, 1)) *  _multipliers[number.Last().ToUpper()];
}
```